# Export Paragraph bundles

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, paragraphs, console

I know `drupal config:export:content:type` is for exporting a content type. Is there a way to do this for a Paragraph bundle?

`drupal config:export:paragraph:type` doesn't work/exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out it can be done with the `config:export:entity` command.

`drupal config:export:entity paragraphs_type [PARAGRAPH_TYPE] --module="[YOUR_MODULE]" --optional-config --remove-uuid --remove-config-hash --include-module-dependencies`

Answer (score 1):

Does anyone have a Drupal 9 way of doing this now that Drupal console is not moving across to Drupal 9?

Comment: There are a few open pull requests to make Drupal Console D9 compatible. Also this should have been a comment ;-)