# Organizing config for use with a module

Tags: configuration

I've recently learned about adding a `config/optional` directory to a module to provide config items that will be imported upon enabling the module if there are no conflicts.

Is there an easier way to retrieve config for use in this way than cherry-picking it out of a site's config directory? For instance — if I wanted a module to include the config for a menu, a content type, etc is there a convenient way to retrieve all config related to those items?

Comment: I think that's what the Features module does these days

Comment: You can also check out config partial export.

Answer (score 1):

Use a config export Console command with the options --module and --optional.

Example for [config:export:single](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export-single.html):

```
drupal config:export:single --name=system.site \
 --remove-uuid --remove-config-hash \
 --module mymodule --optional
```

Add `--include-dependencies` to export dependencies of the configuration as well.

For exporting content types including fields and display modes use [config:export:content:type](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/config-export-content-type.html).

Or more generic for any config entity type see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283094/47547) (not yet included in the documentation).