# Create module that create Content Type

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm developing module that creates a content type. I saw the same question and there was a solution. I had tried it but it didn't work.

job_post.info.yml

```
name: Job Post
description: A job posting content type
type: module
package: Pro Drupal Development
core: 8.x
```

job_post.module

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$content_type = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::create([
    'type' => 'new_content_type',
    'label' => 'new content type',
  ]);
  $content_type->save();
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There is a "Node" module and a  "Field UI" module doing exactly this, and both are part of Drupal core.

Comment: Sorry I haven't got it. I should create custom content type. How can I do it if I need to create module for this?

Comment: You do not need a custom module for this, these are modules part of Drupal core. You can do this using a point & click interface: Go to `Manage > Structure > Content types` (in the Admin Toolbar) or visit the url `/admin/structure/types` and click the button "Add content type"

Comment: Yes, I know that I can do this. But it is not my goal...

Comment: @Hudri – OP maybe wants to create a shippable module to provide some features and a new content type upon installation. Although it would be nice if they'd clarify about this in their question, OP?

Comment: Why is it so dificult. I just need a module that creates content type with some fields and that's all. I don't need to make it using Drupal interface. I have to make it programmatically. It is my task.

Comment: @ectuser if you export the configuration of created content type to module/config/install directory the content type will be created automatically when the module is installed.
That's how Drupal core creates default content types (Article and Basic page). Check out core/profiles/standard/config for examples.

Comment: The module code above has zero context in what function it is in, it’s likely it was never called to begin with.

Comment: @Hudri There is at least a core module that implements a new content type in code and there is also an installation profile adding new content types. That is not wrong, and it is something a module would need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The code from your question should work in a hook_install(). But you need a lot more configuration for a content type, which you can create the easiest way in UI. See the [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283510/create-module-that-create-content-type#comment352596_283510) of @Hudri.

Then export the configuration to the config folder of your module, see [Organizing config for use with a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283257/organizing-config-for-use-with-a-module/283268#283268)