# Is there a way to selectively export specific relevant configuration into custom modules?

Tags: 8, configuration

I'm learning D8 and gaining familiarity with the configuration management aspects of drush.

All my configuration is exported into my **config/sync** directory and I cherry picked the relevant files and moved them into a **config/install** under my custom modules.

However, I'm having trouble when I had to rebuild my site due to some vagrant issues and I came across the following type of errors:

> Unable to install Questions due to unmet dependencies: field.field.node.quiz.field_questions (node.type.quiz), views.view.quizes (node.type.quiz, rest, serialization)

**Is there a way to selectively export specific relevant configuration into my custom modules directly?**

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283268/47547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the awesome [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module as a base to export complex configurations that contain multiple dependencies as a base of my new module and then start building my custom functionality. All major distributions are using features module as it saves a lot of time and it is very reliable.