# How do I generate a custom content entity bundle?

Tags: 8, entities, console

I created a custom content entity with Drupal console version 1.9.2. Everything is working fine.

To use all the configuration and settings of my custom entity type in different bundles, I want additional modules that create bundles of my custom content entity.

I tried to execute `drupal geb` which creates configuration files within my custom module for a new node type (bundle of the node entity), but there is no option to create a bundle of my custom entity type.

Do you know how to generate boiler plate code for custom content entity bundles?

Comment: How did you generate your custom content entity? Did you specify `--has-bundles=true`?

Comment: > Did you specify --has-bundles=true?

Yes, i did.

Comment: I also installed the group module, which introdues the group entity and tried to create a new group type with drupal console.

Comment: I just hand code most custom entities or copy/paste :) So I wasn't aware, but `drupal geb` looks like only generates `node types`, the command is either labelled bad or doesn't work? See [`generate:entity:bundle` allow to add bundles to non-node entity types #3418](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/drupal-console/issues/3418)

Comment: Even when the issue is resolved this wouldn't generate more boilerplate code, because the boilerplate code is already generated by specifying `--has-bundles=true`. Then you can simply create bundles in UI (the boilerplate code includes the config forms) and export those bundles into the module config folder, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283090/export-paragraph-bundle-with-drupal-console