# Creating a Paragraph type programmatically

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a custom module that is installed on a number of sites. In an hook_update_n function I would like to add a completely new *Paragraph type* (not actual instance of a Paragraph) to every site, using the same configuration.

Adding or updating fields to an existing type is well documented, but I can't find out how to create an actual type (node or paragraph) programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. To start with, the config files for a paragraph type should be placed in the config folder of the module, for which there is now a console command. See [Export Paragraph bundle with Drupal Console](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283090/export-paragraph-bundle-with-drupal-console)

Then there is the general problem, how sites can update the config of an already installed module. You'll find different solutions in this topic [How do I update the configuration of a module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164713/how-do-i-update-the-configuration-of-a-module)